# Como implementar dicionários no padrão Multithreaded Singleton

Tags: c#

O padrão [Multithread Singleton](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff650316(v=pandp.10)) me atende no sentido de possibilitar o uso de *"variáveis globais"* em minha aplicação. Seu uso ocorre através dos recursos de `get` e `set`, como é possível notar.

Como de forma semelhante, posso fazer o mesmo com uma variável do tipo `Dictionary`?

```
using System;

namespace Program
{
    class Global
    {
        public sealed class Session
        {
            private static volatile Session instance;            
            private static object sync = new Object();

            private Session() { }

            public static Session Instance
            {
                get
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                    {
                        lock (sync)
                        {
                            if (instance == null)
                            {
                                instance = new Session();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return instance;
                }

            }            
            public bool glb_login   { get; set; }
            public string UserID    { get; set; }
            public string IPAddress { get; set; }
            public string PortName  { get; set; }    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: até onde eu sei um `Dictionary` não é um elemento serializável, você teria de implementar sua prórpria serialização para ele. Se quer serializar, seria mais fácil usar uma estrutura mais simples, como `IList` por exemplo

Comment: Caio, não sei se te ajuda, mas tem um exemplo em 2 partes de C# Singleton no VBMania, a saber:  
DESIGN PATTERN - SINGLETON PARTE #1 - http://www.vbmania.com.br/index.php?modulo=detalhe&id=8830

Comment: @FabioIn. Eu agradeço, mas não consigo ter acesso ao conteúdo por não ter cadastro no site.

Comment: @CaiodePaulaSilva, o cadastro é 100% gratuito...

Answer (score 1):

> O padrão Multithread Singleton me atende no sentido de possibilitar o
>   uso de variáveis globais em minha aplicação

De acordo com o código que você postou é difícil de perceber se você realmente entende a afirmação que você deu.

Este padrão dá garantias absolutas que a variável é instanciada apenas uma vez, mas não dá qualquer outra garantia. Ou seja ainda é possível que duas threads escrevam numa propriedade do objecto existente ao mesmo tempo, causando problemas de estado.

Se o objetivo for garantir que duas threads não podem escrever ao mesmo tempo, então o código não está correto. Uma possível solução seria a seguinte:

```
class Global
{
    public class SessionState
    {
        public bool glb_login   { get; set; }
        public string UserID    { get; set; }
        public string IPAddress { get; set; }
        public string PortName  { get; set; } 
        //Outras propriedades

        public SessionState Clone(){
            //Atenção este método copia as propriedades por valor!
            //Isto quer dizer que se você tiver uma referência, o objeto alterado será o mesmo
            return MemberwiseClone() as SessionState; 
        }
    }

    public sealed class Session
    {
        private static volatile Session instance;            
        private static object sync = new Object();
        private SessionState _sessionState;
        private Session() { }

        public static Session Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    lock (sync)
                    {
                        if (instance == null)
                        {
                            instance = new Session();
                            _sessionState = new SessionState();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return instance;
            }

        }

        public SessionState State {
            get{
                lock (sync)
                {
                    return _sessionState.Clone();
                }
            }
            set{
                lock (sync)
                {
                    _sessionState = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Agora adicionar o seu dicionário seria uma questão de mudar o método `Clone` para retornar uma instância nova com o dicionário novo, com os mesmos dados. E aceder à sua sessão seria feito através de `Session.Instance.State`.

Por curiosidade esta confusão toda deste padrão pode também ser substituída por uma versão bem mais simples:

```
private static Session instance = new Session(){
    State = new SessionState()
};
```